# IIS6.0 Application Pool

Tags: iis-6, application-pool

Is there anyway how to check which website is being used with that pool without browsing each website and checks its assigned pool?

I have approximately 35 websites and I can't afford browsing the websites one by one....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop down the app pool in inetmgr - all the websites should be listed underneath (they are on my servers)...

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS Manager MMC, you can see the application pools node and look in each app pool, or you can open the properties of each site and look at the app pool assigned to it.

There are also a few tricks available for managing app pools that I can dig up if thats what you are looking for.

You should not be "browsing" the sites to see what is what, unless I am not getting what you mean by that.